# MATLAB error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'struct'

Tags: matlab

I tried these commands:

```
im=imread('untitled_test1.jpg');
im1=rgb2gray(im);
im1=medfilt2(im1,[15 15]);
BW = edge(im1,'sobel'); 

msk=[0 0 0 0 0;
 0 1 1 1 0;
 0 1 1 1 0;
 0 1 1 1 0;
 0 0 0 0 0;];
B=conv2(double(BW),double(msk));

Ibw = im2bw(B);
CC = bwconncomp(Ibw); %Ibw is my binary image
stats = regionprops(CC,'pixellist');

% pass all over the stats
for i=1:length(stats),
size = length(stats(i).PixelList);
% check only the relevant stats (the black ellipses)
if size >150 && size < 600 
    % fill the black pixel by white    

    x = round(mean(stats(i).PixelList(:,2)));
    y = round(mean(stats(i).PixelList(:,1)));
    Ibw = imfill(Ibw, [x, y]);

else
    Ibw([CC.PixelIdxList{i}]) = false;
end;
end;
```

(here I have another command lines, but I guess the problem is not because of them.)

```
labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage, 8);     % Label each blob so we can make measurements of it
blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, Ibw, 'all');   
numberOfBlobs = size(blobMeasurements, 1);
```

I got this error message:

```
??? Error using ==> subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'struct'.

Error in ==> test2 at 129
numberOfBlobs = size(blobMeasurements, 1);
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're getting that error because you have created a *variable* called "size" which shadows the built-in *function* [SIZE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/size.html). Instead of calling the *function* to compute `numberOfBlobs`, MATLAB instead tries to *index* the variable using the structure `blobMeasurements` as an index (which doesn't work, as the error message shows).

In general, you shouldn't give a variable or function the name of an already existing function (unless you [know what you're doing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html)). Just change the name of the variable in your code to something other than "size", issue the command [`clear size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/clear.html) to clear the old size variable from the workspace, and rerun your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message tells you that the error is in `numberOfBlobs = size(blobMeasurements, 1);`. `subsindex` is most likely used in `size(..., 1)` to access those elements.

I assume that `blobMeasurements` is an array of structs (or a single struct), for which that operation is not completely defined.

Why don't you use the `length` command as before? That worked a little earlier in your code.